# Formatting Unconventional Date

Tags: r, date, formatting

I'm having trouble formatting a list of dates in R. The conventional methods of formatting in R such as as.Date or as.POSIXct don't seem to be working.

I have dates in the format: `1012015`

using

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(data$Start_Date), format = "%m%d%Y")
```

does not give me an error, but my date returns

`"0015-10-12"` because the month is not a two digit number.

Is there a way to change this into the correct date format?F

Comment: Is there any general assumption can be made to the format, such as the last 4 digits are always year and the first 2-4 digits are month and date (if so, is 111 Nov 1st or Jan 11st)?

Comment: Yes, the last 4 digits are always the year and first 2-4 digits are month and date. The data is in chronological order, but I'm not sure if R would be able to make that distinction in regards to your question.

Comment: _what is the correct answer_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lubridate` package can help with this:

```
lubridate::mdy(1012015)
```

> ```
> [1] "2015-01-01"
> ```

The format looks ambiguous but the OP gave two hints:

- He is using `format = "%m%d%Y"` in his own attempt, and
- he argues the issue is *because the month is not a two digit number*

Answer (score 0):

This uses only base R.  The `%08d` specifies a number to be formatted into 8 characters with 0 fill giving in this case `"01012015"`.

```
as.POSIXct(sprintf("%08d", 1012015), format = "%m%d%Y")
## [1] "2015-01-01 EST"
```

Note that if you don't have any hours/minutes/seconds it would be less error prone to use `"Date"` class since then the possibility of subtle time zone errors is eliminated.

```
as.Date(sprintf("%08d", 1012015), format = "%m%d%Y")
## [1] "2015-01-01"
```